# One page website, show/hide divs, menu button will not stay selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a one page website with a menu (pictures, css roll over...), that will display a different div when each menu button is clicked. Only one div will be shown at time though and if one is already open it should be hidden. This is working well.

The problem I am having is that that the menu button which shows the result will not stay selected i.e. on the same picture as the roll over (hover).

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="home"><a href="javascript:showHide('content1');" title="Home"><span class="displace"></span></a></li>
    <li class="credits"><a href="javascript:showHide('content2');" title="Credits"><span class="displace"></span></a></li>
    <li class="idea"><a href="javascript:showHide('content3');" title="Idea"><span class="displace"></span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content1">home text</div>
<div id="content2">credits text1</div>
<div id="content3">idea text</div>​
```

**JS / jQuery :**

```
function showHide(d)
{
var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
var divs=['content1','content2','content3'];
for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
  {
  if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i]))
    {
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display='none';
    }
  }
onediv.style.display = 'block';
}


$(function stay() {
    $('menu').click(function stay() {
            $('menu').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

    });
});
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/anKT3/159/

I've tried creating a function to change the class, but I've not had any luck.

Comment: I am looking for function that will be flexible if i will ad more buttons ( around 20)...

Comment: also if you could add some code that when clicked the second time, it will hide the div

Comment: I appreciate if you can tell the reason to change your correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `stay()` function to be as follows:

```
$(function stay() {
    $('.menu li a').click(function stay() {            
            $('.menu li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');                        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anKT3/161/)

```
$(function stay() {
    $('ul.menu li a').click(function () {
            $('ul.menu li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

    });
});
```

Comment: This is nice - but how can i do a close"x" inside the box so i can close it? I tried: click `$(this).parent().hide();` but no luck